# How can I display images as thumbnails using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is my site currently: [jaykasten.com](http://jaykasten.com)

I have thumbnails in a grid that link to the full images in a lightbox. Right now, my site loads a thumbnail image as well as the full image.

Is it possible to use the full image files and select a part of them to display as a thumbnail, as to avoid having to load up the extra thumbnail images? Using only HTML and CSS preferably.

Comment: yes.  But what have you tried?

Comment: and "link" is a no no, you should isolate your code here.

Comment: sure, you can do `<img src="fullimage.jpg" width="100" height="100">`, but then you're forcing your users to download every single one of your large images. you'll kill their browsers with ram usage, kill their data connection with overage charges, etc... That's why there's small images for thumbnails, and the original larger ones to act as link targets.

Comment: Loading the full size image as your thumbnail is actually worse off... cause you will be loading the large, full-size image flies.  Loading small thumbnail size images is ideal, and then when clicked, the lightbox should make a server request for the large full-size image.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you would want the thumbnail instead of the full image, since the full image will take longer to load. 50 thumbnails at a few K each vs 50 full res images at several meg each. However I digress.

This can easily be accomplished using background image. If you create a div, anchor, span, whatever you want, and set the `background-image` property to use your final image, you can then scale and size your image however you want and it will cutoff whatever you don't use. As an added bonus, I don't believe background images stop page loading nor cause glitches in layout, so all in all, they work pretty well.

However I would still recommend only loading what the user wants at high res, since it will increase load times of the page otherwise. You could also look into something like https://github.com/teleject/hisrc or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading. Either of these would probably be preferable to loading all high resolution images on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `background-clip` and `background-origin`. Like this:

```
#element{
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```